# Why am I getting a different in div location?

Tags: asp.net

So I've created an image tagger that saves coordinates to the the database, and then I call those coordinates with an erb block on the main page which displays a div at said location (.tagged). However when the tags are displayed on the main page, they are not in the location they were in when I tagged them in the connections page. Anyone have any ideas as to why this is? Thanks in advance.

[Main page results](http://jsfiddle.net/NF3jn/3/)

[Image tagger on connections page](http://jsfiddle.net/filkinsteez/vATcn/29/)

ERB on the main page:

```
<% if @new_manual.present? %>
<% n = 0 %>
<% @new_manual.steps.each do |step| %>
    <% n += 1 %>

    <% i_connection = Contact.find(step.input_contact) %>
        <span class="i_contact i_contact<%= n %>" data-pos-x="<%= i_connection.pos_x %>" data-pos-y="<%= i_connection.pos_y %>"  data-pos-width="<%= i_connection.pos_width %>" data-pos-height="<%= i_connection.pos_height %>" ="spanid<%= n %>" data-index="<%= n %>"></span>


    <% o_connection = Contact.find(step.output_contact) %>
        <span class="o_contact o_contact<%= n %>" data-pos-x="<%= o_connection.pos_x %>" data-pos-y="<%= o_connection.pos_y %>"  data-pos-width="<%= o_connection.pos_width %>" data-pos-height="<%= o_connection.pos_height %>" id="spanid<%= n %>" data-index="<%= n %>"> </span>
        <% cord = CordType.find(step.contact_item) %>


<div class="main_panel">
<div style='margin: auto; width: 600px;'>
    <div id="image_panel<%= n %>" style="float:left; width:600px; position:relative;">
        <%= image_tag(i_connection.image.image.url(:large)) %>
<div class="i_tagmap<%= n %>"></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="main_panel">
<div style='margin: auto; width: 600px;'>
    <div id="image_panel<%= n %>" style="float:left; width:600px; position:relative;">

        <%= image_tag(o_connection.image.image.url(:large)) %>
<div class="o_tagmap<%= n %>"></div>
</div>  
</div>  
</div>

<% end %>   
<% end %>
```

Comment: Those <% %> signs sure don't look like jQuery. Please retag your post.

Comment: There is insufficient information here to answer your question, I think. You're using a lot of custom methods here with no explanation of what / how they perform.