# why aren't these divs in the same position?

Tags: jquery, css, ruby-on-rails-3, image

So I've created an image tagger that saves coordinates to the database, which has been implemented on a page designated for tagging images. I then call these images with an erb block on the main page to iterate through the respected coordinates and then use jQuery to display a div (.tagged) at said location. However when the tags are displayed on the main page, they are not in the location they were in when I tagged them on the connections page. The coordinates are the same, but their positions are not. Anyone have any ideas as to why this is? Any help would be much appreciated.

[HTML generated from the main page](https://gist.github.com/filkinsteez/6067091)

[HTML generated from the tagger page](https://gist.github.com/filkinsteez/6067110)

[jsFiddle of the tagger (includes CSS)](http://jsfiddle.net/filkinsteez/vATcn/31/)

ERB Block that iterates through the images. In this particular case there are four images.

```
<% if @new_manual.present? %>
<% n = 0 %>
<% @new_manual.steps.each do |step| %>
    <% n += 1 %>

    <% i_connection = Contact.find(step.input_contact) %>
        <span class="i_contact i_contact<%= n %>" data-pos-x="<%= i_connection.pos_x %>" data-pos-y="<%= i_connection.pos_y %>"  data-pos-width="<%= i_connection.pos_width %>" data-pos-height="<%= i_connection.pos_height %>" ="spanid<%= n %>" data-index="<%= n %>"></span>


    <% o_connection = Contact.find(step.output_contact) %>
        <span class="o_contact o_contact<%= n %>" data-pos-x="<%= o_connection.pos_x %>" data-pos-y="<%= o_connection.pos_y %>"  data-pos-width="<%= o_connection.pos_width %>" data-pos-height="<%= o_connection.pos_height %>" id="spanid<%= n %>" data-index="<%= n %>"> </span>
        <% cord = CordType.find(step.contact_item) %>


<div class="main_panel">
<div style='margin: auto; width: 600px;'>
    <div id="image_panel<%= n %>" style="float:left; width:600px; position:relative;">
        <%= image_tag(i_connection.image.image.url(:large)) %>
<div class="i_tagmap<%= n %>"></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="main_panel">
<div style='margin: auto; width: 600px;'>
    <div id="image_panel<%= n %>" style="float:left; width:600px; position:relative;">

        <%= image_tag(o_connection.image.image.url(:large)) %>
<div class="o_tagmap<%= n %>"></div>
</div>  
</div>  
</div>

<% end %>   
<% end %>
```

jQuery (How the tags are displayed on the main page)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

$('span.i_contact').each(function() {                
    var pos_width = $(this).data('pos-width');
    var pos_height = $(this).data('pos-height');
    var xpos = $(this).data('pos-x');
    var ypos = $(this).data('pos-y');
    var taggedNode = $('<div class="tagged" />')
    taggedNode.css({
        "border":"5px solid red",
        "width":pos_width,
        "height":pos_height,
        "left":xpos,
        "top":ypos
    });

    var n = $(this).data('index')
    $('.i_tagmap' + n).append(taggedNode)  
    console.log(taggedNode.position())    
});

$("span.o_contact").each(function() {            
    var pos_width = $(this).data('pos-width');
    var pos_height = $(this).data('pos-height');
    var xpos = $(this).data('pos-x');
    var ypos = $(this).data('pos-y');

    var taggedNode = $('<div class="tagged" />')
    taggedNode.css({
        "border":"5px solid red",
        "width":pos_width,
        "height":pos_height,
        "left":xpos,
        "top":ypos  
    });
    var n = $(this).data('index')
    $('.o_tagmap' + n).append(taggedNode)        
});
});
</script>
```

This is kind've a difficult thing for me to explain, so if there is anything I am leaving out that could be beneficial, I will be happy to add that in as well.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why am I getting a different in div location?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17821516/why-am-i-getting-a-different-in-div-location)

Comment: Can you include screenshots describing the problem?